# Expressing a sequence of actions using 〜たとき?

Tags: grammar, nuances

I am aware that one can explain that to things happen at the same time using *plain non past form* + とき:

> 電車に乗るとき転びました。"I fell when I got on the train (I was going through the door when it happened)"

I am not quite sure about the following nuance, though : *plain past form* + とき　means the first action was over when the second happened :

> 電車に乗ったとき転びました。 "I fell when I got on the train (I was already inside the train when it happened)"

Would it *roughly* mean the same thing as :

> 電車に乗った後転びました。"After I got on the train, I fell"

Eventually, would it be correct to express that I read a book before I went to sleep using :

> 本を読んだとき寝ました。

Comment: See if as two states (not tense), accomplished and non-accomplished. AーたB is when A is done, then B. You can even use it speaking of the future. ５０歳になった時にヨーロッパいく。 = I'll go to Europe once I turned 50.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 電車に乗ったとき転んだ is roughly the same as 電車に乗った後転んだ.  However, there is a slight difference.  The former implies that the action 転ぶ happened *right after* the action 電車に乗る: *I fell just after I got on a train.*  電車に乗った後転んだ does not have this implication, and it just means: *I fell after I got on a train*.

本を読んだとき寝た sounds strange whereas 本を読んだ後寝た sounds perfectly normal.  I am not sure why, but I suspect that if an action V takes time, it is unnatural to use Vしたとき and instead we use some other constructs such as Vしているとき, Vした後, and Vし終わったとき depending on what we mean by it.